# How to make clickable span text in Jetpack Compose

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

So I want to make a footnote-like feature in compose that highlight texts that contain numbers and clickable also. for the example:

[image: Text with Footnote]

I made this once without Jetpack Compose (View XML) with SpannableString builder, filtered the texts with regex, and applied it into setText().

How can I make this in Jetpack Compose?

Comment: example: https://gist.github.com/shmehdi01/d1a1d60becc6397a763a6f139af112d8

Comment: @Halifax I tried it, but how to filter it only with numbers? this is what I got: https://imgur.com/a/BwrIasP

Comment: Underline the text?

Comment: Not just the underline, but it's supposed (in my picture) the sentences with numbers spanned also. I just wanted only the numbers get spanned, excluding the alphabets

Comment: you can only intercept the string one by one,judge the position of the string，and then add an underscore

Comment: I have done this with a combination of using Annotated String and the ClickableText composable: You can find more here:
https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/ui/text/AnnotatedString.Builder

and 

https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/text#get-click-position